# Select most popular categories based on records assigned to them

Tags: mysql, join, count

**Problem:** *I want to know what are the most popular categories based on their records which are assigned to each category*

**Database structure:**

```
categories.id
categories.title

records.id
records.category_id
records.title
records.views
```

**Goal:** *Let's say there are 1000+ items in `records` table, which are assigned differently to each categories, and have random number of `records.views`. I know how to JOIN multiple tables, but I have no idea how to count all views of records in each category and show that.*

**Expected results:** *I expect to have output something like this, shown below:*

```
CATEGORY #1
    id = 21
    title = Fruits
    views = 381

CATEGORY #2
    id = 24
    title = Snacks
    views = 8875

CATEGORY #3
    id = 47
    title = Toys
    views = 381

CATEGORY #4
    id = 25
    title = Milky-wilky products
    views = 8875
```

Any tips how to achieve that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a very simple query with aggregation:

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.title, SUM(r.views) AS views
FROM 
    categories AS c
  LEFT JOIN 
    records AS r
      ON r.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY
    c.id, c.title ;
```